# How to build and open composed url with labels or textboxes

Tags: vb.net, google-chrome, internet-explorer, url

I use this code:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim url1 As String = "https://www.google.com.mx/search?q=" & adress.Text
    Process.Start(url1)
End Sub
```

also I try with + instead of &
chrome opens but just "https://www.google.com.mx/search?q=" as URL, missing always the control text part!

How I must format this code?

Comment: This is a lesson on how to think like a developer. When you encounter something like this, there are things that you can do for yourself.  The first thing should be to copy a URL from a browser that works and test it. If that works, compare it to your URL to see what's different.  To do that, you need to look at the actual URL, NOT the code that builds it.  Use your eyes to actually see what value your variable contains and compare that to the contents of a variable set using a URL from a browser that you know works.

Comment: You will also need to url-encode any special characters that may be in adress.Text

Answer (score 0):

This solve the problem

```
Private Sub Search_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Search.Click

    Dim MyUrl As String = (adress.Text)
    Dim EncodedURL As String = System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(MyUrl)
    Dim url2 As String
    url2 = String.Format("https://www.google.com.mx/search?q=" & EncodedURL & ", " & adress.Text & ", " & country.Text)
    Process.Start(url2)
End Sub
```